# Wordpress CSS on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

**strong text**I'm working on wordpress blog which is working fine on laptop and desktop but when i open it on mobile the css is not working on mobile. How can I fix this Issue? [This is link of issue](http://theangelsint.com/blog)
why isn't this code working?

Comment: yes i want to fix it @SahilDhir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **main problem** is because of your **content wrapper class**. it has been given a **fixed width of 1022px** which is causing the problem. Change the width to percentage when it renders on mobile devices. **Also there are the following errors which I have encountered and fixed.**

> So add this css at end of your style.css file and you are good to go
>   for mobile devices ;)

```
@media(max-width:767px){
.wrapper{ max-width:100%; width:90%; margin:0px auto; padding:0px;}
.site-content{width:100%;}
.site-content article{width:100%; box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
.widget-area .widget{width:100%}
}
```

Comment: bro @sahilDhir its wotk but my main problem is that the buttons are not picking the css if I give css with (max-width: 479px) it applies on desktop and laptops rather than on mobile

Comment: Please share your media query and the position where that media query css is placed?

Comment: @media(max-width:479px)
{
 .wp_comments_box{background-color: yellow;}
}
This is my media query but its not working

Comment: are you placing this at end of style.css or somewhere above?

Comment: yes I'm placing this